# Reading two lists containing filenames

Tags: shell-script, gnu-parallel

I am taking two lists having filenames with paths and using gnu-parallel to process the files from the two lists.
However,The command is able to use only files from the first list and not the second list,when I check my output.I have tried various options in this.e.g. giving the filetype in `--readFilesIn` (which is where the error is)

```
reads_list=/comb_fastq/fq1.list
reads_list2=/comb_fastq/fq2.list

for fastq in `cat $reads_list`;do
  rsync -av $fastq $TMPDIR/input/ 
done

for fastq in `cat $reads_list2`;do
     rsync -av $fastq $TMPDIR/input2/
done

parallel -j $NSLOTS --xapply \
  "STAR \
--genomeDir $TMPDIR/reference_genome \
--genomeLoad LoadAndKeep \
--runThreadN 4 \
--readFilesIn ../input/{1} ../input2/{1}
```

Comment: It would help if you would post the error...  Also, if you remove the for loop for `read_list`, does the for loop containing `read_list2` work

Comment: yes it works as i can see the files being copied to TMPDIR.The issue is in --readFilesIn option only as I dont know how to input two files one from each list after being copied.I have tried --readFilesIn {1} {2} as well.There is no such error but the second files is not being read.First is read twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not telling GNU Parallel $reads_list and $reads_list2. So I am puzzled how you would expect GNU Parallel to guess that it should use these.

By rsyncing in parallel as we go (instead of everything before running first job) it might be faster, too. My guess is that this is enough:

```
parallel -j $NSLOTS --xapply \
  "rsync {1} $TMPDIR/input/{1};\
  rsync {2} $TMPDIR/input2/{2};\
  STAR \
  --genomeDir $TMPDIR/reference_genome \
  --genomeLoad LoadAndKeep \
  --runThreadN 4 \
  --readFilesIn ../input/{1} ../input2/{2}" :::: $reads_list $reads_list2
```

Consider walking through the tutorial http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html which covers this and more. Your command line will love you for it.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense +1

Comment: I am working on the cluster.So I am copying files using rsync to $TMPDIR to be more efficient.

Comment: Probably --readFilesIn ../input/{1} ../input2/{2} as well?

Comment: Also,In the last line,would it make sense to take input from /input and /input2 once files are synced , rather than :::$reads_list1 and $reads_list2?